# Laptop is not booting up (HP Pavilion dv6t-2000)

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, laptop, crash, data-recovery

When i start my PC (HP Pavilion dv6t-2000, Win 7 Home Premium) it showed the message that there is some hardware-software failure and shown the error with error code as **0xc0000225**..

Now it shows an message saying that my BIOS has been transfered to hibernate mode as temperature of laptop was increased than the specifications.

The exact error that i get is as below;

> "The system bios has detected your notebook PC was placed in hibernation to avoid overheating .
>   The system is now operating normally and your data should remain intact.
>
> Overheating may occur if the cooling vents are blocked or the operating temperature exceed the specification. The notebook PC should return to normal operation once the situation is resolved.
>
> System Temperature (90D)"

I am now planning to format my laptop but i need to recover the data and hence i am doing that using Ubuntu Live CD (Ubuntu Version: 10.04 LTS) but unfortunately that dvd just shows the option of Try-Install ubuntu but the ubuntu never really starts!

What can I do?

Comment: Have you not tried my answer???? You should take a look for that may be it would helpful for you and leave a feedback for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the hard disk from your laptop (sometimes this is fiddly work and needs care) and plug it into a desktop PC using an IDE/SATA to USB adapter or enclosure - they are relatively inexpensive.

If your laptop is overheating, check that dust isn't clogging it's (tiny) fans and that the fans are turning. The laptop will have air vents at the side, you should be able to both hear and feel air being blown out.

Comment: i guess there is overheating.. how to check for fans in the laptop? how to check if there are working fine..

Comment: the model is HP DV6 (2000 series i guess)

Comment: Yes, a label is there underside.. Which info do you want and how would that be helpful in solving the problem?

Comment: Model Number is dv6t-2000

Comment: awaiting your comment

Comment: @romilnagrani let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1072/discussion-between-redgrittybrick-and-romilnagrani)

Comment: If it's anything like a HP ProBook, start by taking out the battery and removing screws under there. Then you can slide the panel above the keyboard off.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to see this [Link](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Other-Notebook-PC-questions/Startup-Error-System-Temperature-90D/td-p/158801). And first you should call the HP service to assist you. [Here](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware/dv8-1010er-and-linux/td-p/235241) is the same problem with the `dv8-1010er`.

There user gives this solution

SOLUTION - I found a very simple fix for this error - Shut down the laptop - Remove the power cord - Remove the battery - Disconnect the cmos battery - Press the power button for 30 seconds - Wait 2 more minutes - Re-connect the cmos battery - Insert the battery - Connect the power cord.

Note: You must enter the bios on your first boot and set the Date and Time.

Hope this will help you. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

[See this thread about overheating](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Other-Notebook-PC-questions/How-to-prevent-and-deal-with-overheating/m-p/295146) and how to deal with it.

[When booting from an Ubuntu CD/DVD](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/use-ubuntu-live-cd-to-backup-files-from-your-dead-windows-computer/) you should get this screen, choose the "Try Ubuntu...." option

[image]

Comment: i know how to boot from Ubuntu and how to take backup. the options are actually coming, but the cd never starts. read my question carefully

Comment: " that dvd just shows the option of Try-Install ubuntu", your question needs rewording to be clear. You must BOOT from the Ubuntu CD to get the TRY option